# Woocomerce Wordpress PHP wrap shop <ul> items in <div>

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am building a theme and I'm having a little bit of trouble, I am trying to modify the /shop page template.

My current HTML output is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
<section id="nav_menu-3" class="col-md-3"> [nav menu items go here] </div>  // this is a sidebar widget
<ul class="products columns-3"> <li> [woocomerce products go here]</li></ul> 
</div>
```

I have been able to add the first row using the hook - add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop') and after shop loop.

I now want to wrap the  class in another  so the output is like this:

```
<div class="row">
<section id="nav_menu-3" class="col-md-3"> [nav menu items go here] </div>  // this is a sidebar widget
<div class="col-md-8"> // start new div
<ul class="products columns-3"> <li> [woocomerce products go here]</li></ul> 
</div> // end new div
</div>
```

If i Add this in my current function it seems to break the layout - here is my before shop loop item.

```
function  woocommerce_product_columns_wrapper() {
    $columns =  woocommerce_loop_columns();
    echo '<div class="row">';       
 }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', ' woocommerce_product_columns_wrapper', 40 
);
```

The same function is used with the after_shop_loop to close the div. How can I add the extra  to wrap it all up?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot or link of the page.

Comment: I have been able to fix it using Jquery and $( ".products.columns-3" ).wrap( "<div class='col-md-6'></div>" ); however I was wondering if there is a way to do it in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a custom class before `<ul>` HTML tag on WooCommerce shop and archives pages:

First, read "[Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)" official documentation, that explains you how to override woocommerce templates via a theme.

**Note** for "Premium Themes":
On some premium themes, they can use already some customized WooCommerce templates, so you will have to use them instead. If you are using a child theme with it, copy the related template to your child theme, respecting the same folder hierarchy.

Once understood this, the related template to edit is `loop/loop-start.php`.
Open/edit it and replace:

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
    <ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
```

Now, open the `loop-end.php` and close the tag

Save… You are done.

Comment: thank you i was looking for that better than using jquery

Answer (score 0):

in woocomerce go to templates copy all files from there to your theme folder

then you see there is loop folder containing loop-start.php 
code like

```
<ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
```

you can change this to

```
<div class="col-md-8">
 <ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
```

And there is one more loop-end.php

```
</ul>
```

change this to

```
</ul></div>
```

Thanks